# running an Executable file and then waiting for that particular exe file to no longer be running

Tags: java, javascript, process, exe

I want to run an AHK executable and then have java wait for that executable to terminate it's own process at the end of it's script and then continue, is there a function to monitor whether or not a particular exe is running? And if it's running to wait until it has stopped?

for example in AHK you could do:

```
IfExist, Appname, 
{
insert code
}
```

I would do this project using just AHK but because AHK is so flimsy with variables and incrementing i can't get it to work it's IF and Else Statements properly

or if even possible, how can i make Java pause itself for a period of time

all im really looking for is a simple bit of code to run a .exe and the a bit fo code to wait for it to not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as simple as one line of code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(<insert executable file here>).waitfor();
```

PS: It is just one line so I didn't mind, but this is not a place to obtain full working code from others. The usual response is "look here, do it yourself", unless the OP post relevant code with a small part missing, which is not the case here.
PS2: Please consider accepting Jim's answer as it was the correct one.

Comment: thanks i expected too much for so little, thanks for your help. also what do i put in the brackets for .waitfor(); the name of process again? it asks for a string

Answer (score 4):

You want to read up on [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to launch the exe file and then [`java.lang.Process.waitFor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) to wait until the process is complete.  If you want to feed data to the process via its stdin, or read its stdout or stderr, then you have a much more complex task involving threads to handle the streams so that the process doesn't block.

Comment: no the process i am launching is completely self regulated, and is in a different, codign language, all iw ant is to launch it, wait for it's process to not exist, then have the main script continue

Comment: also if someone could provide a some code of what im looking for with something laong the lines of <insert executable file here> in the palce where i put the executable files name and directory that would much more appreciated than a simple look here, do it yourself

Comment: +1 for the right links to the API in there. I tend to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str)` instead of `new ProcessBuilder(str).start()`. I never quite figured out what's different between them, though...