# Run a vb generated exe file from java and wait the end of execution

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [running an Executable file and then waiting for that particular exe file to no longer be running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761652/running-an-executable-file-and-then-waiting-for-that-particular-exe-file-to-no-l)

I want to run a vb generated exe file from java and wait for the file to finish execution.

I tried to use `p.waitFor()` but with no success.

Is there any other alternative ?

Comment: This question is a bit vague - what does "no success" mean? Got a bit more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should actually work:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(<file.exe>).waitfor();
```

Unless stdin/stdout of the Subprocess are involved then you could get in Deadlocks:

The JDK's Javadoc documentation provides following information:

> some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard
>   input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream
>   or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess
>   to block, and even deadlock.

This is good explained [here](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=2)